# How to remove double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a problem and cannot figure out what to do.

Question: I need to remove a double quote, inside double quotes

---

String example:

"MIKE YANICK","412 A AVE "E"," ","NADIEN PA"," ","190445468"

As you can see, the letter E inside "412 A AVE "E" has an extra double quote.

---

I need to remove it.

Here is what my outcome should be:

"MIKE YANICK","412 A AVE E"," ","NADIEN PA"," ","190445468"

---

- I cannot use expressions because the pattern changes every time.
- The string.replace will not work, because you would need to hard code the values
- Reading values in between double quotes does not work, because it gets thrown off by the quote in the middle

Please help...

Comment: Can you fix it at the source?  How is this text generated?

Comment: We cannot fix the source. It comes from a third party....

Comment: `I cannot use expressions because the pattern changes every time.` what do you mean by this? If the `pattern changes every time`, how can you possibly hope to fix it?

Comment: @InternetEngineer, you should talk to the third party, because their format is broken.  In a text-quoted, comma delimited file, quotes meant as text should be escaped.

Comment: Yes the location of the double quote changes position all the time.
Sometimes its 2 characters off the closing double quote, and sometimes its in the complete middle. I have no idea how to fix this, but I am willing to ask for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with your example:

```
Regex.Replace("\"MIKE YANICK\",\"412 A AVE \"E\",\" \",\"NADIEN PA\",\" \",\"190445468\"",
    "(?<=\")([^,]*)(?=\")",
    m => m.Value.Replace("\"", string.Empty)) ;
```

Output:

```
"MIKE YANICK","412 A AVE E"," ","NADIEN PA"," ","190445468"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
(?<!(^|,))"(?!(,|$))
```

This will match any double quote (`"`) that isn't proceeded by the start of the string, or a comma, and isn't followed by a comma or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, look for `",` . If the quotes are not next to a comma, delete the quotes.

Comment: Along with this, you might want to remove all spaces between the `"` and `,` first.

Comment: Except you need to account for the start and end of the string which isn't next to commas.

Comment: Yes, that could work in some if the instances, but not all. Sometimes the double quote is what off the closing double quote

Comment: @InternetEngineer: What is that supposed to mean? If the extra double quote is *after* the closing quote, i.e. your string goes `"","`, then why not consider the second `"` as the closing quote and the first one as the spurious one?

Comment: if the `""` is in the first or last index, don't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using replace?

Something like:

```
string test = "\"MIKE YANICK\",\"412 A AVE \"E\",\" \",\"NADIEN PA\",\" \",\"190445468\"";
string[] fields = test.Split(new char[] {','});
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
bool first = true;

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if(first)
    {
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
            result.Append(",");
    }

    result.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", field.Replace("\"",""));
}

Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Old : {0} New: {1}", test,result.ToString()));
```